# Why is my XPath expression "unable to locate element"?

Tags: xpath

Below is the HTML code, I am trying to make a XPath expression for the user name text box which is inside the table.

I tried following expressions:

1. To traverse the table: `//table[@id='Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV']`
2. To reach out to the user name: `//input[@id='Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:password']`
3. To reach to Log in button: `//div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]/a/span[2]`

I'm getting following error message:

> Unable to locate element:
>
> ```
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:username']"‌​}
> ```

I am very new to XPath. I am reading the stuff on google and trying on what I have understood out of my readings.

```
<div id="mainContent">
<div id="Login" class="content">
<div id="Login:LoginScreen:ttlBar" class="screentitle">
<input id="Login:LoginScreen:_msgs" type="hidden" name="Login:LoginScreen:_msgs"/>
<span id="Login:LoginScreen:_msgs_msgs"/>
<div id="Login:LoginScreen:0" class="info">The submitted user name/password is invalid.</div>
<table id="Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV" class="dv ">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<table id="Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:0" class="dvColumn" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="empty-cell">
<img height="1px" width="1px" border="0" src="images/trans_pixel.gif"/>
</td>
<td class="empty-cell">
<img height="1px" width="1px" border="0" src="images/trans_pixel.gif"/>
</td>
<td class="inputLabel">
<span>User name</span>
</td>
<td class="empty-cell">
<img height="1px" width="1px" border="0" src="images/trans_pixel.gif"/>
</td>
<td class="inputValue">
<input id="Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:username" class="textBox" type="text" contenteditable="true" onblur="EventHandlers.onBlur(event)" onfocus="EventHandlers.onFocus(event)" helptext="__UseTitle__" size="20" style="text-align: left" delayonchange="false" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;" onkeydown="DHTML.cancelBubbleIfNoAltKeyOrEnter();" onchange="if (EventHandlers.valueChanged(event, this)==false) return false;" value="" label="User name" name="Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:username"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What XPath expressions have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure it it's only me, but I cannot find any input elements in that HTML snippet.

Comment: <table id="Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV" class="dv ">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<table id="Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:0" class="dvColumn" 
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="inputLabel">
<span>User name</span>
</td>
<td class="inputValue">
<input id="Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:username" class="textBox" type="text" contenteditable="true" value="" label="User name" name="Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:username"/>
</td>

Comment: Don't put code into comments. Edit the question instead.

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong copy paste, I am new to this.

Comment: It's just barely readable, and the question should be self-contained. Also add what you tried, folks here don't like people just begging for code without own effort.

Comment: Thanks Jens for mentioning me the modifications in my post. I was really trying hard to understand the concept behind xpath.

Comment: Question looks really great now. All of those queries seem fine on first sight. What error message do you receive, how are you running the expressions? Does your HTML include any XML namespaces (if it is XHTML)?

Comment: Step one seems unnecessary. Also, what is giving you the error message? Can you post some code and tag this post with the language?

Comment: My HTML do not have any XML namespaces. I just tried to look more detailed into the HTML code and source code. It is using multiple frames in this, I think I should identify which frame contains the username input and then try the xpath.

Comment: Yes, this will probably be the issue. XPath does not look into frames, although Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools will "embed" their HTML.

Comment: @ Mark,Jens, Thanks for the responses, I am trying to use xpath for Selenium web driver. Now when I tried with the frame URL it is working fine for me. I should read more on how to work with xpath having frames in code.

Comment: @user3464008 XPath has nothing to do with frames. Frames are completely independent HTML pages embedded into another. Webdriver will have to do the navigation to present the content to the XPath parser.

Comment: @Mark, I have used below code, now I am able to locate the webelement:driver.switchTo().frame("top_frame");
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:password']"));
password.sendKeys("123");

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the actual problem may be malformed XML: Lines 30, 31, and 32 are open tags without any closure.

I copied your XML into my text editor, Notepad++, which has the XML Tools plugin installed. Once I changed those three tags to `<tr />`, I used the XPath expression evaluator in the plugin to try your original XPath statement, `//input[@id='Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:username']`, and it found the node without any problem.

(I tried to include a screenshot, but my rep isn't high enough. The screenshot may be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgj3p.png).)